# How to sign into a YouTube account in React Native to access private playlists

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I am building a React Native app and I need to be able to view and play YouTube playlists.

I have gotten API keys and can successfully play public YouTube videos by their ID.

I don't know where to start with getting OAth2 credentials to be able to access the users Playlists.

Answer (score 2):

there is not any specific module for react native to log into youtube, but you can look into youtube v3 docs for [Using OAuth 2.0 for JavaScript Web Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication), and check **client side web apps** section. Once you get the required credentials its pretty straightforward to retrieve the [playlists](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list).

if you are looking for a third party library you can check this [library](https://github.com/indatawetrust/react-native-youtube-oauth)

Comment: Please provide example if possible

Answer (score 0):

The page to get started with youtube oauth is [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)

```
var GoogleAuth; // Google Auth object.
function initClient() {
  gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
      'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest']
  }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
  });
}
```

After initializing, you will need to get permission from user etc, which is shown in the documentation.

Comment: 'gapi-client' seems to not work with React Native, it throws errors so I will probably have to use endpoints instead

Comment: it appears there's no javascript client sdk for javascript for youtube, so yes you may want to use endpoints instead.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Please provide endpoints instead code if possible?

Comment: if you go to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#creatingclient and then u select OAuth Endpoint, you can see the endpoints and the options. The link is in the answer above actually.

Comment: ok thank-you @SomeoneSpecial if you have demo and other code related please share with me